# MySQL WordPress Query throwing error and empty data

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to run an MySQL query to pull in custom fields froma custom post type.

I'm having difficulty with my query:

```
SELECT pm_cdate.meta_key AS call_lead_date,
pm_ctime.meta_key AS call_lead_time,
pm_cnumber.meta_key AS caller_number,
pm_cduration.meta_key AS call_duration,
pm_cstatus.meta_key AS call_status
FROM 1ltw_posts p 
INNER JOIN 1ltw_postmeta AS pm_cdate
ON p.ID = pm_cdate.post_id
INNER JOIN 1ltw_postmeta AS pm_ctime
ON p.ID = pm_ctime.post_id
INNER JOIN 1ltw_postmeta AS pm_cnumber
 ON p.ID = pm_cnumber.post_id
INNER JOIN 1ltw_postmeta AS pm_cduration
 ON p.ID = pm_cduration.post_id
INNER JOIN 1ltw_postmeta AS pm_cstatus
 ON p.ID = pm_cstatus.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'tel_leads'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

The error in the error log is as follows:

`[Tue Aug 05 10:38:14 2014] [warn] [client 80.80.80.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: WordPress database error Unknown column 'call_lead_date' in 'field list' for query SELECT COUNT(call_lead_date) as cnt_total FROM 1ltw_posts made by do_action('wp_ajax_get_wdtable'), call_user_func_array, wdt_get_ajax_data, PHPDataTable->buildByQuery`

Someone please tell me where I'm going wrong with this.

PS - this has to be done in MySQL (and not PHP)

Comment: The error is from another query.. I see no `COUNT(call_lead_date)` here!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is not related to the query above.

If you look closely at the error it gives you a snippet of the query:
`SELECT COUNT(call_lead_date) as cnt_total FROM 1ltw_posts`

This is not part of the query you have posted.

The error itself is telling you that the column `call_lead_date` doesn't exist in the table `1ltw_posts`, but that will probably become more apparent when you find the code causing the issue.